# Symfony ICU translation trailing newline after the translated message

Tags: symfony, internationalization, symfony4

I followed the official Symfony documentation on [how to translate messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html) using the new ICU message format.

Inside the `messages+intl-icu.pl.yaml` file I have the following entry:

```
pages:
  show:
    ratings_title: Opinie
    ratings_count: >
      {count, plural,
        =0    {brak opinii}
        one   {jedna opinia}
        few   {# opinie}
        other {# opinii}
      }
```

Which is consumed as follows:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ 'pages.show.ratings_title'|trans }}</h1>
    <sub>({{ 'pages.show.ratings_count|trans({'count': count}) }})</sub>
</div>
```

Which results in:

```
<div>
    <h1>Opinie</h1>
    <sub>(brak opinii
)</sub>
</div>
```

While the expected output should be:

```
<div>
    <h1>Opinie</h1>
    <sub>(brak opinii)</sub>
</div>
```

So my question is: **how to remove that trailing newline character after the translated message?**

Comment: Thank you for downvotes. I’ve notified Symfony developers about this and they have decided to update the official documentation because of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok this was simply due to misconfigured YAML file. In order to strip YAML's trailing newline inside a [multi-line string](https://yaml-multiline.info/) I should have written the translation entry as follows:

```
pages:
  show:
    ratings_title: Opinie
    ratings_count: >-
      {count, plural,
        =0    {brak opinii}
        one   {jedna opinia}
        few   {# opinie}
        other {# opinii}
      }
```

Notice the use of `>-` instead of `>`